# Регулярное выражение: удалить лишние скобки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, mongodb

Делаю пользовательский поиск по БД сайта. БД  - `MongoDb`, поэтому, из введеной пользователем строки, хочу сделать регулярное выражение типа: `/(word)|(word)/gi`.
У меня это почти получилось:

```js
var search = 'one two three ';

var startRegExp = /(\w+)\b/g;
var t = search.replace(startRegExp,"($1)");//каждое слово оборачиваю скобками
console.log(t);

var f = t.replace(/[^(\w+)+]/g,""); //из получившейся строки удаляю все, что находится за скобками
console.log(f);

var finisfRegExp = f.replace( /\)\(/g, ")|(" ); //слова в скобках разделяю вертикальной чертой "|"
console.log(finisfRegExp);
```

На выходе получаю строку такого вида `(one)|(two)|(three)`. А "почти", потому что, если в строке поиска добавить скобку ")" или "(" - они не удаляются. Получается что-то типа  `(one)|((((two)|(three)` Может быть есть и еще символы, которые не удаляются, но таких пока не нашел. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, удалить скобки из строки поиска. Или как-то улучшить сам принцип создания нужного регулярного выражения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю просто добавить ещё одну замену, она должна быть самой первой и просто удалить все скобочки из строки.

```
var regExpDelBrackets = /[()]/g;
var t = search.replace(regExpDelBrackets, "");
```

Но полагаю что другие левые символы тоже могут попадать, проверьте например `'@'` или `'#'`, поэтому удаляйте их все

```
var regExpClear = /[^\w]/g;
var t = search.replace(regExpClear, "");
```

Но можно сделать ещё проще, просто находя все слова, именно их и берите, а вы берёте изначальную строку заменяя в ней слова. То есть используйте функцию `match`

```
var startRegExp = /(\w+)\b/g;
var matches = search.match(startRegExp);
rez = "";
for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
   rez += "(" + matches[i] + ")"
   if(i != matches.length-1) {
     rez += "|";
   }
}
```

Comment: Все гениальное просто, спасибо!)

Comment: @Дмытрык я обновил ответ, код в конце проще и эффективнее работает

Comment: @Дмытрык Пожалуйста!